# Spam customer registrations, CAPTCHA not stopping it, Max field rule being bypassed

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, captcha

Over the last few days we have been getting spam customer registrations,  every 90mins about 20 "accounts" are created in a few mins, with the first name being eg Рассадина Зинаида Пантелеймоновна, мы определили победителей совместного конкурса с помощью Google и Random.Org: https://www.google.com/#btnI=RandomOrg-%32&q=b%54%63%320%31%38rU

Its seems the idea is to spam using our welcome email with the link in the first name field going to a targets email ( we got a reported spam warning from hotmail)

We already have  captcha running as suggested in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144150/preventing-spam-direct-post-request-customer-registrations-in-magento

and we have changed the maxlength on the create account page for the first and second name from 255 to 50 thinking at least we can stop the there goal of posting the long url link in the first name. But that is being bypassed and they are still able to post first names with 200+ characters.

Is there a way to enforce the 50 character limit?

Comment: use google recaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html

Comment: @NikunjVadariya    If you check the other question, its seems that google recaptcha does not work as the bots go it createpost directly, bypassing it

Comment: I am also getting exactly the same thing, magento captcha bypassed and also bypassed max fields. 

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144150/preventing-spam-direct-post-request-customer-registrations-in-magento

Suggested that magento captcha should stop it, but like you I have magento captcha enabled and it hasn't stopped it. (Though I did increase the captcha to 8 chars + case sensitive and there are fewer, but not stopped 100%).

I hope someone can shed some light on this soon :(

Comment: @loginid Looking at the logs the create accounts were coming from different ips but the ip requesting the captcha was always the same ip address in germany, so I going to try to block that ip, so see if that makes difference ( only a temp fix granted)

Comment: so blocking that ip address has stopped the last round of attempts of account creations, so it looks like they are using that to "read" the captcha, so that will stop them ... until they use a new ip

Comment: @PaddyD - thanks for the advice. Which logs are you checking to see the ip address? I tried checking the apache access_log but can't seem to find the create attempts.

Comment: @loginid - we are using nginx ( not apache) so its the nginx access logs.  I just search for "create" in the logs to find them. ( most of our customers create accounts at our onestepcheckout, very few view the registration form, so they are easy to find).

Comment: Try extension https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows.

Go with phpmyadmin to the database table `customer_eav_attribute` and edit the **record 5 (attribute_id 5)**.

Edit content table column `validate_rules -> max_text_length "; i: 255" to "-> max_text_length"; i: 65`.

`attribute_id 5` is the first name and the values in the validate_rules are checked before the update to the database.

Because the bot almost always enters 155 characters. Should it only be rejected from now on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rama.

Is there a way of doing this via configuration rather than via the DB?

Comment: @Rama -> Unfortunately we did not find anything in the configuration in the backend. Also in the phtml files the maxlength = "" information does not work.

We have also installed various honeypot extensions but without success.

Only the database solution described above could stop the bot. We are happy that it works.

Comment: @TigrayM.L. - thanks for your suggestion.  Blocking the ip accessing the captcha has been working for me so far, but I don't think that will last long, so I will try your suggestion once they start happening again.  I was going to try a honeypot next (don't like installing too many extensions unless i have too), so interesting that you found they don't work.

Comment: Working solution! I set the limit to 25!

Comment: just to update, they started using a new ip after a few weeks and I used the suggest answer, and so far its been working fine.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked for me as well. However, I'm on magento 1.9.2.2 and the attribute id for the first name and last name are attribute_id 1 and 2.

Comment: just an update: russian bots have started shortening the text to 55-56 characters, but I realised the actual form on the website only allows 40 characters, so I changed the limit to match.... lets see how long that works for

Comment: Thank you very much Rama.. This solution work for me too but spammers are smart and now they are entering the 65 characters Or might be if will reduce the limit they will come with that reduce limit. 

So I think now we have to find something different solution for this . 

If you have please update here..

Comment: Is there another solution. The limit to 25 characters even, doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the following code for adding google invisible captcha and the following code server-side validation.

```
<?php class Addpeople_Validatecaptcha_Model_Customer_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer {

public function validate()
{
    $errors = array();
    if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getFirstname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The first name cannot be empty.');
    }

    if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The last name cannot be empty.');
    }

    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getEmail(), 'EmailAddress')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid email address "%s".', $this->getEmail());
    }

    $password = $this->getPassword();
    if (!$this->getId() && !Zend_Validate::is($password , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The password cannot be empty.');
    }
    if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array(self::MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH))) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
            ->__('The minimum password length is %s', self::MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }
    if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array('max' => self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH))) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
            ->__('Please enter a password with at most %s characters.', self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }
    $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
    if ($password != $confirmation) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
    }

    $entityType = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('customer');
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'dob');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getDob())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The Date of Birth is required.');
    }
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'taxvat');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getTaxvat())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The TAX/VAT number is required.');
    }
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'gender');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getGender())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Gender is required.');
    }

    if( Mage::getStoreConfig('validate_captcha/server_side_validation/enabled') ) {
        $errors = $this->validateCaptcha($errors);
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        return true;
    }
    return $errors;
}

private function validateCaptcha( $errors ) {

    /* additional reCAPTCHA validation */

    $action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if ( $action == 'createpost' ) {

        $captcha = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('g-recaptcha-response', 1);
        if ( $captcha == '' ) {

            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please check the reCAPTCHA field to continue.');
        } else {
            $params = array();
            $params['secret'] =  Mage::getStoreConfig('validate_captcha/server_side_validation/secret_key');
            $params['response'] = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('g-recaptcha-response', 1);
            $params['remoteip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $params_string = http_build_query($params);
            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?'.$params_string;

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $response = curl_exec( $ch );

            $result = json_decode( $response, true );
            if ( trim( $result['success'] ) != true ) {

                // This will be shown at the top of the registration page
                $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('reCAPTCHA unable to verify.');
            }
        }
    }

}}
```

Please refer my website for layout and config file.

https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/invisible-recaptcha-register-form-magento/

Comment: where is code added?  "Please use the following code for adding google invisible captcha and the following code server-side validation", that wording seems to imply the are 2 different sets to code to be added in 2 different places,  can you explain more please?

Comment: This answer is extremely vague, most users are going to be looking at this and trying to search more detail on how to do this and it's over complicated. Magento's back end has the functionality to add the captcha which should be enough in most cases and if not alternative methods on top such as the answer for the field limitation as an example.