# customer_eav_attribute, fist name validate rules, what does "s:15" mean?

Tags: magento-1.9

Is is following on from this question:
[Spam customer registrations, CAPTCHA not stopping it, Max field rule being bypassed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228528/spam-customer-registrations-captcha-not-stopping-it-max-field-rule-being-bypas)

That answer worked, but in the last few days its been happening again, and the bots are getting 60+ characters in the first name field even though it limited to 65 (as suggested in the answer) in database.  I then changed it to 42 (as it a limit of 40 in the actual website), but they are still get though.

So the rule was:

```
{s:15:"max_text_length";i:255;s:15:"min_text_length";i:1;}
```

and now its

```
a:2:{s:15:"max_text_length";i:42;s:15:"min_text_length";i:1;}
```

What does "s:15" mean, is that adding to the 42?

ThankS

Comment: That is serializable of an object.

Comment: oh, so nothing to do with the character length then

Comment: You can modify the value by using unserializable function.