# Spam account registrations, limiting characters in database not working

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-account, registration, captcha

We had a problem of spam account registrations the last year, and the answer to this question worked great

[Spam customer registrations, CAPTCHA not stopping it, Max field rule being bypassed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228528/spam-customer-registrations-captcha-not-stopping-it-max-field-rule-being-bypas)

We limited the character count to 42 and that stopped the spam accounts.

But last week they started again ( not as frequent). They are getting between 40-65 characters into the first name field the first name attribute is limited to 42 characters:

```
a:2:{s:15:"max_text_length";i:42;s:15:"min_text_length";i:1;}
```

Looking at the access logs I can see the same Russian IP hitting the captcha about the same time the account is being made, and when I ban that IP address the accounts stop.... until they get a new (Russian) IP address.

I don't understand how they are getting around the database validation rules for that field.

Thanks